# Escolher arquivos diferente e imprimir de uma vez

Tags: pdf, impressão

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?

Gostaria de saber como poderia estar criando um script para receber arquivos PDF, DOC, XLS... e imprimir todos de uma vez (enviar para impressão) em vez de abrir um por um e imprimir.

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Em qual linguagem deseja o seu script? Qual o sistema operacional utilizado?

Comment: Estou pensando em fazer em PHP.

Comment: Você vai percorrer todos os arquivos de uma pasta ou vai enviá-los por uma pagina web por exemplo.

Comment: enviar pela pagina web e também percorrer um pasta!

Comment: Primeiramente tem o upload de arquivos: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=upload+arquivos+PHP então a impressão de um arquivo: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=impress%C3%A3o+direta+com+php Posteriormente iterar sobre vários arquivos. Onde fica sua dúvida?